# Globaly remove any AlertDialogs

Tags: java, android

I have an Application class that has a timer which is checking for login status.
If login status changes, that class logs out the current user from this device and before that it displays an `AlertDialog` telling the user  that app will log him out. In this class, I store current context, from which I can manipulate current activity.

Problem comes when I have an active `AlertDialog` in any activity or fragment and my status changes and that logout dialog can't be shown and throws exception saying unable to add window.

Now my question is how could I check if any dialog is on top of current activity, and how can I force remove them all and show my logout dialog?

Comment: easiest way would probably be to keep a global reference to your dialog(s), if they are showing, dismiss them

Comment: So do you thing I should keep refrence for any active dialog, just like my context, and then just simply dismiss it?

Comment: `for any active dialog` realistically you'd only have one, right ? i don't think it's possible to be showing more than one at a time, so you'll probably only have one global dialog reference which you can then dismiss

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself poorly, I will try with global AlertDialog reference, and just change that reference every time I have a new dialog up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a global dialog instance. I will use a simple example to explain this. I have created a `MainActivity`.

Inside it I have the

1. `onCreate` - This will be called when your app starts.
2. `buildAlertDialog` -  This will create one instance of the alert dialog.
3. `onStopMethod` - This will be called when the activity stops.
4. `onDestroy()` - This will be called when the application instance is destroyed by the OS.

In the `onCreate` method, you can check if the dialog is showing and close it and do somthing else.
I have added code to dismiss the dialog automatically when the activity stops.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext(); // Get application context

        buildAlertDialog(context);

        // To show the dialog do this
        alertDialog.show();

        // You can check if it showing then close it before you do something
        if (alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.dismiss(); // Dismiss
            // Then do something
        } else {}
    }

    private void buildAlertDialog(final Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Sample AlertDialog");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This is a sample AlertDialog to demonstrate global instance");
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
        });

        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); // Create dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        alertDialog.dismiss(); // Dismiss dialog onStop
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        alertDialog.cancel(); // Dismiss dialog onDestroy
    }
}
```